# Hangfire throws error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_HangFire_Hash'" when manually trigger job from the dashboard

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql

We recently encountered an issue with Hangfire. Our project is utilizing the following package versions:

Hangfire.AspNetCore: 1.8.0
Hangfire.Core: 1.8.0
Hangfire.SqlServer: 1.8.0

The problem arises when attempting to manually trigger a job from the dashboard, and we occasionally encounter the error provided below. It appears to be related to a unique constraint issue, though we are uncertain about the root cause.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_HangFire_Hash'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key
> in object 'HangFire.Hash'. The duplicate key value is
> (recurring-job:IWorkOrderBackgroundService.WatchInProgressWorkOrders,
> LastExecution).
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
> 'PK_HangFire_Hash'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
> 'HangFire.Hash'. The duplicate key value is
> (recurring-job:IWorkOrderBackgroundService.WatchInProgressWorkOrders,
> NextExecution).
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
> 'PK_HangFire_Hash'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
> 'HangFire.Hash'. The duplicate key value is
> (recurring-job:IWorkOrderBackgroundService.WatchInProgressWorkOrders,
> LastJobId).
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_HangFire_Set'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'HangFire.Set'. The duplicate
> key value is (recurring-jobs,
> IWorkOrderBackgroundService.WatchInProgressWorkOrders).
> The statement has been terminated.  The statement has been terminated.  The
> statement has been terminated.  The statement has been terminated.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
> ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
> isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
> shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean
> inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
> completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache,
> Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlCommandBatch.ExecuteNonQuery()     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerWriteOnlyTransaction.b__17_0(DbConnection
> connection, DbTransaction transaction)     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.b__0(DbConnection
> connection, DbTransaction transaction)     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.<>c__DisplayClass40_0`1.<UseTransaction>b__0(DbConnection connection)     at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection[T](DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func`2 func)     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseTransaction[T](DbConnection
> dedicatedConnection, Func`3 func, Nullable`1 isolationLevel)     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseTransaction(DbConnection
> dedicatedConnection, Action`2 action)     at
> Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerWriteOnlyTransaction.Commit()     at
> Hangfire.RecurringJobManager.TriggerJob(String recurringJobId)     at
> Hangfire.RecurringJobManager.Trigger(String recurringJobId)     at
> Hangfire.Dashboard.DashboardRoutes.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_27(IRecurringJobManager
> manager, String jobId)     at
> Hangfire.Dashboard.RouteCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(DashboardContext
> context, String jobId)     at
> Hangfire.Dashboard.BatchCommandDispatcher.Dispatch(DashboardContext
> context)     at
> Hangfire.Dashboard.AspNetCoreDashboardMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)     at

Answer (score 0):

Check if the IGNORE_DUP_KEY feature is set on the tables, see the install script for reference:

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/Install.sql

```
    -- SqlServerStorageOptions.UseIgnoreDupKeyOption will yield much better results with INSERT/UPDATE operators
    -- instead of MERGE for [Set] and [Hash] tables. This change is also compatible with older clients, since
    -- MERGE operator is used there, so those clients are forward-compatible with these changes.
    ALTER TABLE [$(HangFireSchema)].[Set] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
    PRINT 'Enabled IGNORE_DUP_KEY option for [$(HangFireSchema)].[Set] table';

    ALTER TABLE [$(HangFireSchema)].[Hash] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
    PRINT 'Enabled IGNORE_DUP_KEY option for [$(HangFireSchema)].[Hash] table';
```